# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'execute'

Tags: reactjs, fetch, setinterval, use-effect, usecallback

I can't seem to find an answer to this despite trying different things. I keep getting the error:

```
 Line 18:5:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'execute'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
printWarnings
```

on this file:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

export const createEffect = (fs, dependency) => {
    const[data, setData] = useState({})

    const execute = () => (
        fs().then(res => {
            setData(res)
        }).catch(err => {
            // do some magic
        })
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        execute()
        const interval = setInterval(execute, 15000)
        return(() => clearInterval(interval))
    }, [dependency])

    return(data)
}
```

The TLDR is I need to make a fetch request to a specific API function defined by `fs()` either every 15 seconds or when some global state changes, defined by `dependency`. I also want to capture the data and any errors hence why I'm wrapping the `fs()` around with a couple of `then()` and `catch()` blocks.

The following code gives me the warning at the top when I execute it inside my functional component:

```
import createEffect from './components/createEffect'
~~~
let api = new api('http://localhost:8080/v1');
const[status, updateStatus] = useState(true);
const summary = createEffect(api.getSummary, status)
```

Any idea how I can fix this? I'm new to React useEffect and not 100% if this is the right way to go about doing something like this? Specifying `execute` as a dependency inside my useEffect call causes the app to constantly re-render. I'm running `execute()` before calling `setInterval()` because I want the query to run every 15 seconds AND when the component first renders.

For more context: I'm making a dashboard as a sample project and want to query multiple api endpoints every 15 seconds or immediately when some global state changes. If the global state does change, I want to reset my HTTP polling from whatever time that is left back to 15 seconds.

Comment: Are you using `execute` anywhere other than inside the useEffect? If not, you could simply move the declaration inside of the useEffect to get rid of the warning

Comment: if I move `execute()` inside my useEffect function, I get the same error expect this time it's about the `fs()` function: 
`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fs'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linting error is very straight just says exactly what you need to do, either leaving the dependency array of `useEffect` as empty, or add the `execute` function into it.

Basically, because you access the `execute` function inside the effect callback, and as it's created within the same scope as the effect, React requires it to be a dependency.

To resolve the problem with continuous re-rerendering, you need to make your execute function a memoized function by using `useCallback`

Solving it should be as simple as:

```
const execute = useCallback(() => (
    fs().then(res => {
        setData(res)
    }).catch(err => {
        // do some magic
    })
), [setData]);

useEffect(() => {
        execute()
        const interval = setInterval(execute, 15000)
        return(() => clearInterval(interval))
    }, [execute])
```

Comment: I did it exactly your way, but now the linter is complaining about the `fs()` function
`React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'fs'` Adding fs as a dependency causes it to constantly re-render.

Comment: Where your `fs` function comes from ? Can you update your question to include it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what additional information I can provide? The `fs` function is a function that is passed in when I import the file and call `createEffect()` since createEffect takes two parameters, a function to execute `fs` and some `dependency` to be added to the useEffect call inside createEffect. The createEffect function is exported like this `export const createEffect = (fs, dependency) => {}` and is called like this: `createEffect(() => api.getSummary(), status)`

Comment: If you're asking what the fs actually is. It's simply a `fetch()` call to an API which returns a promise.

Comment: If you call `createEffect` like this `createEffect(() => api.getSummary(), status)` then surely you will end up having the re-rendering problem because a new function `() => api.getSummary()` is created inside the component scope every single time the component is considered for re-rendering. In JS, function is an object React shallow comparison will consider them different. To solve the problem you have some choice, either taking it out of the component, or make it a memoized function with `useCallback`.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping I could isolate my useEffect call into a separate component and then just pass in the api function and return a value. That way I wouldn't have to implement any logic within my main component. Not sure if this is valid, but could I jut surpress the linting error? Would it have any effect on my component and the way it functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `execute` as a dependency, since the function definition itself isn't changing. Just debug if the component is re-rendering after every call. I think they shouldn't.